# sort dictionary with custom key in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a dictionary with keys in format: [1:ABC, 113:NUX, 78:BUN, 34:POI, 223:NTY]

When I sorted the array of keys, i get the sorted key array as: [1:ABC, 113:NUX, 223:NTY, 34:POI, 78:BUN]

But I want the sorted array as: [1:ABC, 34:POI, 78:BUN, 113:NUX, 223:NTY]

what am I missing here? what additional sort should I add?
* I am using Swift 2

Comment: Dictionaries are not sortable.

Comment: "I am using Swift 2" Why?

Comment: But the info you provided indicates the keys are strings and not numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer:

let arrSortedKeys = keys.sort{$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}